# getselectednode from another bean (primefaces)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, treenode

I have a ManagedBean of a treeNode and other managed bean where i would like to get the selectedNode and from getType i would like to execute some code but the problem i can't get the selectedNode cause every time i get this:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.faces.FacesException: #{dimMan.makeDim()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and this is my two Managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TreeBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2417620239014385855L;
    private TreeNode root;
    private TreeNode selectedNode;
.....
```

and the other one where i would like to make a test of the type of selected node:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dimMan")
@SessionScoped
public class DimenssionManaged {

    @EJB
    DimensionDaoRemote dimService;

    @Inject
    TreeBean treeSelected;
    String select;

    public TreeBean getTreeSelected() {
        return treeSelected;
    }
    public void setTreeSelected(TreeBean treeSelected) {
        this.treeSelected = treeSelected;
    }
    public void makeDim(){

        System.out.println("adding dimen");
        fkey=tTable.getSelectedFk();
        dimUpdate.setFk_dimension(fkey);
        dimUpdate.setType_dimension(selectedType);
        select=treeSelected.getSelectedNode().getParent().getType();

        System.out.println(select);

        if (select=="cube"){
            CubeBase cub=cubManged.getCubUpdate();
            dimUpdate.setCube(cub);
            dimService.creat_dimension(dimUpdate);
        }
        else {
            SchemaBase sh=shmanged.getSchema();
            dimUpdate.setSchema(sh);
            dimService.creat_dimension(dimUpdate);
        }


    }
```

i try also to use this annotation `@ManagedProperty(value =***)`  but it didn't work to so what should i do to get the selectedNode type from in other ManagedBean ?

Comment: `DimenssionManaged` ManagedBean associated with other page? If so once you navigate `TreeBean` will loose its data since its in `ViewScoped`. Post the Facelet code.

Comment: Thx it's work now good job  Kishor P

Comment: Ok I'll post that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DimenssionManaged` ManagedBean associated with other page? If so once you navigate `TreeBean` will loose its data since its in `@ViewScoped`.

Change `TreeBean` to `@SessionScoped` to retain the the data even after navigation, but clearing/refreshing the data again is a concern.